# Time of point colliding with a moving line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

In 2-D space, given a line defined by two points a and b, and a third point c that is not initially (t=0) in the line defined by a and b, is it possible to obtain an expression for the **numerically calculable exact** time of collision (i.e. no irrational expressions) given that each point has its own linear velocity?

e.g.

```
a(t) = a0 + (Va)*t
b(t) = b0 + (Vb)*t
c(t) = c0 + (Vc)*t
```

Comment: To clarify: a, b, and c are two dimensional points $(x_a,y_a),(x_b,y_b),$ and $(x_c,y_c)$, and they change with time, which means that $V_a$, $V_b$ and $V_c$ are also two dimensional vectors? You want the time at which the line formed by $a-b$ collides with the point $c$?

Comment: Yes, the velocity are two dimensional vector consants, and yes I want the time when the line collides with the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c$ will be on the line $ab$ (maybe not between them) if the slope of $ac$ is the same as the slope $ab$, so you need $\frac {c_y-a_y}{c_x-a_x}=\frac {b_y-a_y}{b_x-a_x}$.  This becomes $\frac {c0_y+Vc_y*t-a0_y-Va_y*t}{c0_x+Vc_x*t-a0_x-Va_x*t}=\frac {b0_y+Vb_y*t-a0_y-Va_y*t}{b0_x+Vb_x*t-a0_x-Va_x*t}$.  Clear the denominators and you have a quadratic formula for $t$.  I suspect that does not satisfy your **numerically calculable exact** time of collision because of the square root, but in fact a square root can be as exactly computed as $\frac 13$.  I have ignored issues surrounding division by zero and loss of precision due to subtractions, which are much greater than the problem of square roots.

Comment: I've also come to the conclusion that a quadratic expression must be solved for t. It confuses me though because it seems like a "linear" problem, if that makes any sense. There are obviously many inexact square roots, so I can't have them. I'm curious though as to how subtractions can result in loss of precision.

Comment: Imagine a computer that works in decimal to six places.  If I have a value 1.23456, that has a possible error of $\pm 10^{-5}$ and a relative error of about the same.  If I subtract $1.23000$ I get $0.00456$ which gets updated to $4.56 \cdot 10^{-3}$ but the relative error is now about $2 \cdot 10^{-3}$  This is a **big** topic in numerical computation.  The same computer cannot represent $\frac 13$ any closer than $0.333333$, which is the same type of error you get from square roots.  Unless you use a rational representation, division is no more exact.

Comment: Yes, this is why I chose to use rationals and exact computation.